# 3-columns, align center column to center

Tags: css, html, slider

I have interesting task.

```
<div class="slider">
   <div class="1s">1st slide</div>
   <div class="2s">2nd slide</div>
   <div class="3s">3d slide</div>
</div>
```

css look like this

```
.slider div {
   width: 200px;
}

.1s {
   float:left;
}

.2s {
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.3s {
   float: right;
}
```

This is 3-column slider. It must be 100% width. What can you suggest me to align central slide to center? Minimum marginess beetween central left and central right slide must be 150px.

Now I've got problem that 3d slide is situated under second, how to make it inline?

Comment: Sounds like you want to outsource your day job to SO?

Comment: No, I have an solution with using table-cell, but it only have fixed margin, and don't know how to do not fixed margin.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="slider">
        <div class="fs">
            1st slide</div>
        <div class="ss">
            2nd slide</div>
        <div class="ts">
            3d slide</div>
    </div>


    <style type="text/css">
        .fs
        {
            float: left;
            width: 50px;
        }
        .ss
        {
            float: left;
            margin: auto;

        }
        .ts
        {
            float: left;
            width: 50px;
        }
        .slider
        {
            width: 200px;
        }
  </style>
```

Comment: But if it will be 100% width? and all divs are the same width 200px

Comment: then you can give padding-left to second div as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this,

```
 <style type="text/css">

   .first
    {
        float: left;

    }
    .second
    {
        float: left;
        margin: auto;

    }
    .third
    {
        float: left;            
    }      
    .slider
    {
        width: 300px;
    }

    .slider div{
          width:100px;     
     }

  </style>

  <div class="slider">
    <div class="first">      1st slide</div>
    <div class="second">    2nd slide</div>
    <div class="third">     3d slide</div>
  </div>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/7v28D/